# Initializing a new user

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have a method in my rails project that initializes a new user by copying some properties of another. The method should also retain entered parameters if saving the new user is rejected. [Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) complains that Assignment Branch Condition Size for this method is 42.02/15. How can I improve this?

```
def setup_user_clone
    member_id = (params[:id] || params[:member_id])
    @membership = Membership.find(member_id)
    accounts = @membership.user.accounts.map(&:id) | [@account.id]
    cloned_user = User.new @membership.user.attributes.slice('permissions')
    cloned_user.game_plan_admin = @membership.user.game_plan_admin
    if user_edit_params
      cloned_user.email = invite_email
      cloned_user.permissions = user_edit_params[:permissions]
      cloned_user.accounts = Account.find(invite_app_access.map(&:to_i))
      cloned_user.level = user_edit_params[:user_level]
    end
    profile = SettingsProfile.new @account, cloned_user
    accounts |= [*cloned_user.accounts.map(&:id).to_set]
    @user_edit = UserEdit.new current_user, profile, @membership.user.admin?, accounts, @membership.user.shared_credentials.map(&:id)
    @method = :post
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my notes

- First don't use `#map` and use [`#pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) instead (for database calls), all over your code.

  bad:

  ```
  @membership.user.accounts.map(&:id)
  ```

  better:

  ```
  @membership.user.accounts.pluck(:id)
  ```
- Use eager loading, to reduce queries

  Bad:

  ```
  Membership.find(member_id)
  ```

  Better:

  ```
  Membership.includes(user: :accounts).find(member_id)
  ```

  Because you are using users and accounts in the loops after.
- This whole block could be reduced to a single statement

  ```
  if user_edit_params
    cloned_user.email = invite_email
    cloned_user.permissions = user_edit_params[:permissions]
    cloned_user.accounts = Account.find(invite_app_access.map(&:to_i))
    cloned_user.level = user_edit_params[:user_level]
  end
  ```

  To

  ```
  if user_edit_params
    cloned_user.assign_attributes(
      email: invite_email
      permissions: user_edit_params[:permissions]
      accounts: Account.find(invite_app_access.map(&:to_i))
      level: user_edit_params[:user_level]
    )
  end
  ```
- No idea what this does

  ```
  @membership.user.attributes.slice('permissions')
  ```

  but wouldn't this do the same ?

  ```
  @membership.user.permissions
  ```
- [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)
- And basically just group common stuff into single methods and call the methods inside this method, isntead of having one huge method like this